# Convert GeoPandas linestring from lat long to UTM

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, pyproj

I can convert points from lat long to UTM OK using the following code

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
import pyproj  

wgs84=pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")
utm=pyproj.Proj("+proj=utm +zone=50 +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

x=df['geometry'].apply(lambda p: p.x)
y=df['geometry'].apply(lambda p: p.y)

df['x']=x
df['y']=y

xx,yx = wgs84(x, y)
rx, ry = utm(xx, yx)

df["x"] = rx
df["y"] = ry 

geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df['x'], df['y'],  crs=df.crs)
df['geometry']=geometry
```

For linestring I tried to convert lat/long to UTM using

```
path  = df['geometry'][0]

project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(df.crs),
    pyproj.Proj('UTM zone 50N'))

path = transform(project, path)
```

but get following error:

```
CRSError: Input is not a CRS: UTM zone 50N
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `to_crs`: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.to_crs.html

```py
geometry.to_crs("EPSG:32650")
# or
geometry.to_crs("+proj=utm +zone=50 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```